# Why does my code print every second cidr range?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a line-by-line list of cidr ranges in a txt file. I can't figure out why every second line gets printed.

```
import ipaddress
from sys import argv

script, file1 = argv

with open(file1) as x:
    for reading in x:
        line = x.readline().strip()
        net4 = ipaddress.ip_network(line)
        for i in net4:
            print(i)
```

I'm trying to print every individual IP within all cidr ranges.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`for reading in x` is iterating through `x` one line at a time.

But you're ignoring `reading` and reading another line, with
`x.readline().strip()`.

Instead you can do:

```
with open(file1) as x:
    for line in x:
        net4 = ipaddress.ip_network(line.strip())
        for i in net4:
            print(i)
```

Comment: This worked and makes sense. Thanks a lot. Also thanks Khelwood for editing my post, I'm new here (obviously)

Answer (score 3):

You're reading two lines per loop iteration. Once with `for reading in x:` and again with `line = x.readline()`

A `for` loop iterating through a file object (such as `x` in this case), by default, reads every line. It's more or less equivalent to just doing `.readline()` until the file runs out of lines.

So you can just do

```
line = reading.strip()
```

instead of reading another line.